# Is there a way to change the order of the feature in summary_plot of shap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, shap

I want to decide the order of the feature inside the shap.summary_plot
Here is a code that is working, I want to learn to change the order of the variable instead of having ordered in list of importance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shap
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
X = np.array([[(1,2,3,3,1),(3,2,1,3,2),(3,2,2,3,3),(2,2,1,1,2),(2,1,1,1,1)],
              [(4,5,6,4,4),(5,6,4,3,2),(5,5,6,1,3),(3,3,3,2,2),(2,3,3,2,1)],
              [(7,8,9,4,7),(7,7,6,7,8),(5,8,7,8,8),(6,7,6,7,8),(5,7,6,6,6)],
              [(7,8,9,8,6),(6,6,7,8,6),(8,7,8,8,8),(8,6,7,8,7),(8,6,7,8,8)],
              [(4,5,6,5,5),(5,5,5,6,4),(6,5,5,5,6),(4,4,3,3,3),(5,5,4,4,5)],
              [(4,5,6,5,5),(5,5,5,6,4),(6,5,5,5,6),(4,4,3,3,3),(5,5,4,4,5)],
              [(1,2,3,3,1),(3,2,1,3,2),(3,2,2,3,3),(2,2,1,1,2),(2,1,1,1,1)]])
y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0])

# Updated model with correct input shape
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu',input_shape=(5,5)),
    layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
    layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')  # Adjust the number of output units based on your problem (3 for 3 classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10)

explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model, X)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X)
#print(shap_values)

cls = 0
idx = 0
feature_names = ["Feature1","Feature2","Feature4","Prova4","Feature5"]
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[cls][:,idx,:], X[:,idx,:], plot_type="bar", feature_names=feature_names)
```

Is there a way to choose the order of the feature plotted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hack for me was to set `sort=False` in the function, and then pass in the order myself. This can be done with some argsort between pandas dataframe and numpy, or shap-values can be intermediately converted to Dataframe and then reordered as desired:

```py
# Features dataframe
features_df = pd.DataFrame(..., columns=["a", "b", "c"])

# Decide the order you want for the plot
feature_names_ordered_for_plot = ["b", "a", "c"]

# Order the features_df and the shap-values
features_df_ordered_for_plot = features_df[feature_names_ordered_for_plot]
shap_values_ordered_for_plot = pd.DataFrame(shap_values, columns=features_df.columns)[feature_names_ordered_for_plot].to_numpy()

# Plot
shap.summary_plot(
    shap_values_ordered_for_plot,
    features_df_ordered_for_plot,
    sort=False
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code allow to do that

```
cls = 0
idx = 0
custom_feature_order = ["Feature1","Feature4","Feature2","Prova4","Feature5"]
feature_names = ["Feature1","Feature4","Feature2","Prova4","Feature5"]

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[cls][:,idx,:], X[:,idx,:], plot_type="bar", feature_names=feature_names)
#---
# Find the indices of features in the custom order
feature_indices = [feature_names.index(feature) for feature in custom_feature_order]

# Reorder SHAP values and feature values
shap_values_reordered = shap_values[cls][:, idx, feature_indices]
X_reordered = X[:, idx, feature_indices]

# Calculate the absolute mean of SHAP values
abs_mean_shap_values = np.mean(np.abs(shap_values[cls][:, idx, :]), axis=0)

# Create a bar chart
plt.bar(custom_feature_order, abs_mean_shap_values)
plt.xlabel('Feature')
plt.ylabel('Absolute Mean SHAP Value')
plt.title('Absolute Mean SHAP Values')
plt.show()
```